# Calculate an MD5 checksum for a file in C without opening the file?

Tags: c, linux, md5

I have a list of files in a directory and I want to calculate the MD5 checksum for each of the files.  Is there a way to do this without opening the files?  If not, what library do I use? Is it the md5 library?

Thanks

Comment: check openssl library

Comment: I want to use it in my code, not on the command line.  Not sure if that makes sense or how I can modify my question to make that clear

Comment: Even if you use a third party library (and even if the OS would provide an API for this), to produce the MD5 hash, the file must be opened for reading. If that can't be done, or you need to speed things up, consider pre-calculating the MD5 hash (which will be interesting in case of changes).

Comment: So you want to compute a value that is dependent on the content of the file without looking at the content of the file ? Generating a random number might eventually produce the right value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use openssl library / crypto

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>

...
MD5(a, b, c, d);
```

compile with `-lcryto`

```
gcc code.c -o myexec -lcrypto
```

[OpenSSL Reference](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/md5.html)

Comment: Correct. Although there are many other crypto libraries but openssl is most widely used.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without needing to use -lcrypto?

Comment: you can write your own md5 library, but not sure it will be quick ;)

Comment: @AndieM It's not easy to write and md5 library. But depending on where and why you want to use it there are other options.

Comment: The answer does open and read the file to calculate the hash.